# Correct implementation of robots.txt in a CRA

Tags: reactjs, seo, robots.txt

I currently have a SPA written in react. In my react application I am utilizing react-router-dom in order to define the routes within my react app. I would like to set up my robots.txt file in order to clarify which pages need crawlers.  As it stands I would like only my home page which lives on the '/' route and the Prepare page, which lives on the '/prepare' route to allow crawlers and disallow all other pages.  I am unsure of the correct implementation of a robots.txt file in order to achieve this. My current file looks like the following:

```
# https://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated.